# Calling a class method within a method definition in the same class

Tags: java

So I'm writing a program for an intro Java class.  I'm defining a method to add two fractions together within the class Fraction.  Fraction has 2 variables, numerator and denominator.  Each of these variables has a setter and a getter.  Anyway, I have a problem with my addition method, which is shown below.  I've just sort of tried to implement it in a way that made sense, but I'm sure I did something with calling methods/using objects that doesn't work.

```
public void add(Fraction fraction1, Fraction fraction2)
{
    Fraction fraction3 = new Fraction();

    int a = fraction1.getNumerator;
    int b = fraction1.getDenominator;
    int c = fraction2.getNumerator;
    int d = fraction2.getDenominator;

    fraction3.setNumerator((a * d) + (b * c));
    fraction3.setDenominator(b * d);
}
```

I don't know if the problem is in the method definition, if I can use the object type that way, or if there's something else wrong.  any help would be appreciated, and if I need to provide any information, I'll do so ASAP.

Edit:  The Error was a compiler error, couldn't find object.  I forgot my parentheses after the function call, problem solved.  Sorry for the inconvenience of forgetting to detail my error.

Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think there's something wrong? Indicating why you think there' a problem would help people know how to answer.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When posting a question, it helps us when you tell us what error you're receiving. Is there a compiler error? Does the code throw an exception? Are you getting unexpected output? By giving us more details, we can help with your problem more quickly.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your `get` calls are meant to be methods. Are you getting a compilation error by any chance.

```
int a = fraction1.getNumerator();
int b = fraction1.getDenominator();
int c = fraction2.getNumerator();
int d = fraction2.getDenominator();
```

Comment: That's it, Thanks!  I feel kind of foolish for forgetting that, but I guess that's what learning a language is about.  :P

Answer (score 1):

Your `fraction3` is a local variable, all references to it are lost as soon as the `add` method completes. You could try returning `fraction3` instead of `void` in order to to hang on to it.

Answer (score 1):

Your method is `void`, which means it's not returning an answer. A couple of slight modifications to your code results in a functioning solution:

```
public static Fraction add(Fraction fraction1, Fraction fraction2)
{
    Fraction fraction3 = new Fraction();

    int a = fraction1.getNumerator();
    int b = fraction1.getDenominator();
    int c = fraction2.getNumerator();
    int d = fraction2.getDenominator();

    fraction3.setNumerator((a * d) + (b * c));
    fraction3.setDenominator(b * d);

    return fraction3;
}
```

Notice that I changed the method to `static` since it doesn't modify `this`, changed the return-type from `void` to `Fraction`, and added a `return` statement. Not that this is a *non-destructive* add because it returns a new fraction. If you want to use this style then you should probably just get rid of the *setter* methods since they won't be used, and declare the fields as *final*, setting the numerator/denominator via the constructor instead.

Your other option would be to define a *destructive* addition operation, meaning that the receiver is *updated* rather than returning a *new fraction object* like you do above.

```
public void add(Fraction that)
{
    int a = this.getNumerator();
    int b = this.getDenominator();
    int c = that.getNumerator();
    int d = that.getDenominator();

    this.setNumerator((a * d) + (b * c));
    this.setDenominator(b * d);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just my opinion, but if you are going to have `add` take two arguments, make the method static.  If you are going to have it take one argument, it would not be static, as the second argument is implicitly `this`.

The reasoning for this is if the non-static version takes 2 arguments, then you are using instance a to operate on instance b and instance c?  IMHO that doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

parenthesis are missing in your methods ...

```
int a = fraction1.getNumerator();
int b = fraction1.getDenominator();
int c = fraction2.getNumerator();
int d = fraction2.getDenominator();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `return type` and return `fraction3` from the method as below:

```
public Fraction add(Fraction fraction1, Fraction fraction2)
{
   Fraction fraction3 = new Fraction();

   int a = fraction1.getNumerator();
   int b = fraction1.getDenominator();
   int c = fraction2.getNumerator();
   int d = fraction2.getDenominator();

   fraction3.setNumerator((a * d) + (b * c));
   fraction3.setDenominator(b * d);
   return fraction3 ;
}
```

now you can use this method as :

```
 Fraction resultFraction = add(fraction1, fraction2);
```

If you want to add fraction2 in fraction1 itself i.e.

```
 fraction1.add(fraction2);
```

Then update your method as:

```
public void add(Fraction fraction2)
{
   int a = this.numerator;
   int b = this.denominator;
   int c = fraction2.getNumerator();
   int d = fraction2.getDenominator();

   this.numerator = (a * d) + (b * c);
   this.denominator = (b * d);
}
```